# iPad mini iOS 12.0 - Can't move Notes to Gmail

Tags: ipad, gmail, notes.app

In the Apple Notes app, I see an ICLOUD folder and a GMAIL folder. When I select "Edit" -> "Move All" the only option is to select ICLOUD. **GMAIL isn't an option.**

I am able to copy notes to the ICLOUD folder (but I have a bunch of notes and that seems annoying) and I am also able to "Save to Files" my Drive account. In both cases, the note does reach my google account so I don't think it's an account issue.

[image: Notes view showing GMAIL exists][image: Attempting to Move one Note to GMAIL. GMAIL is not visible in the list]

Comment: Hello Chad, welcome to Ask Different. Do I understand your question correctly that you are trying to move notes from iCloud to Gmail? If you select one iCloud note (not all), don't you have the option to move it to Gmail? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: @jaume that is correct. I've attached screenshots. The first shows GMAIL is a connected account. The second shows my attempt to move a single item, ICLOUD is the only option.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots, I see a note count of zero in the Gmail account. If you select Gmail, can you create a note? If you create a note on another device, does the note sync and show up in the iPad Notes app?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to create a note on my iPhone and see it on my iPad. I also tested the other way around - I was able to create a note on my iPad and see it on my iPhone. Sadly, there is still no option to move notes to my Gmail account.

Comment: Is there any resolution on this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Not that I've found yet. Best I can do is copy & paste everything. :(